# Comparing to a user object in ParseQuery and facing error 102

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to find out all the records that matches a user from a Parse class (namely, UserBeaconTracking). I am able to get correct user object and beacon object to begin with. However, when I use the statement

```
    userBeaconTrackingQuery.equalTo("user", user);
```

Returned Error 102 with an error message "value is expected instead of map type."

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Here is the code snippet:

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.equalTo("username", username);

userQuery.find().then(function(currentUser) { // get the user who sent the request 

    user = currentUser;
    console.log("User" + JSON.stringify(user) + "Beacon Name :: " + JSON.stringify(visitedBeaconName));

}).then(function () { // get the beacons with which user communicated 

    var beaconRelation = Parse.Object.extend("Beacon");
    var beaconQuery = new Parse.Query(beaconRelation); 
    beaconQuery.equalTo("name", visitedBeaconName);
    return beaconQuery.find(); 

}).then(function (beacons) { // get user beacon transaction details   
     console.log("number of beacons " + beacons.length + " " + beacons[0]);

     visitedBeacon = beacons[0];
     console.log("beacon :: " + visitedBeacon);

     var userBeaconTracking = Parse.Object.extend("UserBeaconTracking");
     var userBeaconTrackingQuery = new Parse.Query(userBeaconTracking);
     userBeaconTrackingQuery.equalTo("user", user);
     userBeaconTrackingQuery.equalTo("beacon", visitedBeacon);
     userBeaconTrackingQuery.find({
         success : function (results) {
              visitCounter = results[0].get("count");

              console.log ("Visit Counter :: " +  visitCounter); 

              // get the list of stores associated with the beacon 
              var beaconTable = Parse.Object.extend("Beacon");
              var brandsAssociatedWithBeacon = new Parse.Query(beaconTable);
              brandsAssociatedWithBeacon.get(visitedBeacon.id).then(function(beacon) {
                         typeOfBeacon = beacon.get("type");
                         console.log("Beacon Type ::" + typeOfBeacon); 
                         var beaconBrandRelation = beacon.relation("brand");
                         var query = beaconBrandRelation.query();
                         //return query.find();

                     }); 
         },
         error: function(error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
         }

     }); 
});
```

Comment: What is the type of "user" column in  "UserBeaconTracking" class?

Comment: Resolved: currentUser was an array of user objects. Needed to get first element from that array.